# WMS Layers Theming in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers, mapserver, wms

I have a WMS Layer(using MapServer) and i want to draw it with certain colors from OpenLayers.

Anybody know how to do such thing???

THANKS !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have the geometry in the database try to make a **WKT** layer :)

Answer (score 2):

You can theme WMS layers with custom styles, using SLD (i.e. you specify custom style with SLD or SLD_BODY parameters on your GetMap requests). You can start with Server side support paragraph from http://mapserver.org/ogc/sld.html

Comment: or you can supply a reference to an SLD at a public location with the SLD=& parameter